# function max(bytea) does not exist postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I am new to PostgreSQL and I cannot find the solution to this problem, I need to select the maximum value present in a column of type bytea. Any help is appreciated in advance.

My Query:

```
select MAX (Blob) from test.final
```

My Error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function max(bytea) does not exist
```

Comment: could you update and give an example of what a working `max(bytea)` looks like?

Comment: For the same table in SQL Server same query is resulting in a binary number(Since in sql there is varbinary not bytea) but the number is too large that I would not paste it here.

Comment: What are you storing in the `bytea` column that makes you need the `max()` function. It seems that `bytea` is the wrong type to use. If you want to store a number, use `numeric`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `max(bytea)` is not possible, you could try `max(encode(...))`:

```
postgres=# create table test(name bytea);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into test values ('1234567890');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into test values ('12345678901234567890');
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from test;
                    name                    
--------------------------------------------
 \x31323334353637383930
 \x3132333435363738393031323334353637383930
(2 rows)

postgres=# select encode(name,'escape') from test;
        encode        
----------------------
 1234567890
 12345678901234567890
(2 rows)

postgres=# select max(encode(name,'escape')) from test;
         max          
----------------------
 12345678901234567890
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on `postgresql` documentation aggregation function `max()` doesn't support `bytea` parameter.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html

**Only allowed are.**

```
any array, numeric, string, or date/time
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, but I know this already. Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: @AliMohsin, treat this as text instead of bytea `SELECT max(blob::text) FROM test;`